# I couldnot get the reply from the bot after sideloading to the microsoft team

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a chatbot using bot framework and Bot application(using Visual C#).I deployed my bot to Microsoft team channel.For that, I got the manifest from the bot framework portal after I registered the bot and added some properties(like manifest version, name, description, icons, accent color, bot id etc). Then I zipped the two icons with that manifest file. Then zipped bot package was sideloaded to the team.It didn't show any error. But I couldn't get the reply from that team bot.when I checked in online bot framework test emulator, it was working.The problem is with my team Bot.Please can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please add the **Skype** channel and the **MS Teams** channel to the bot and try again?

Comment: I tried. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you please share your bot id?

Comment: Bot id is ERP Bot.

Comment: **ERP Bot** is a bot name. Could you please provide the bot id from manifest in bot section? It is a GUID which looks something like this: 0a0bebe7-0972-497d-a54d-f838733e1647.

Comment: It's my application ID-b62dd7bb-1364-481e-be05-f53b8fe78c1f

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the system in which bots are registered that we think is causing your problem. There's a fix for this bug but it hasn't been deployed yet.

A possible workaround is to disable the Teams channel, wait 3-5 minutes, then re-enable it. 3-5 minutes later, it should work in Teams.

If that doesn't work, let us know and we can make an ad hoc update for your bot.

Many apologies - a recent change in the Bot Framework portal uncovered a number of unknown latent bugs in our bot registration code.

Comment: Thank you. My bot worked after a day in MS Team after I sideloaded.But I didn't change anything in my manifest or Didn't sideload the bot again.